# How to reset the form using JavaScript?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, commandbutton

```
<apex:page id="page1">
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.JqueryA, 'js/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js')}"/>
<apex:form id="form1">
<apex:inputtext value="{!text1}"/>
<apex:inputtext value="{!text2}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="myFunction();"/>
<apex:commandButton value="List" action="{!list}"/>
<script>
    function myFunction()
        {
        document.getElementById(form1).reset();
        alert("Sundhar");
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

it want reset the form . but i can't able to reset it ?

Comment: Why do you want reset it? Or better question what do you want achieve by doing this?

Comment: when i click in the list for the time it is showing the results and i modify the textbox data and i click .it is throwing the error .so i  want to reset the form the form to modify the search

Comment: Cant you just create apex method and put null in all fields in form?

Comment: i have two button are there first button is to reset and second button is to show list .when i click on the reset button before click the list it is reset the form when i click the reset button after clicking the list it is not working.i need that mainly it has to reset after clicking the list button

Answer (score 2):

You were trying to fetch dom element by id but didn't used string literal in doing so. To retrieve an element with the id ***form1***, you should place the string literal ***form1*** in **(double) quotes**, like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('form1').reset();
}
```

However, even that wouldn't have worked in your case, because it would fetch element with id ***form1***, while your form would probably have composite id, which would include entire component tree above the form itself. I.e. in your case ***form1*** is just **ID of the VisualForce form component**, **not** of the **DOM element** rendered in the browser. The id of the form element rendered in the browser would have probably looked something similar to ***page1;j0;g0;...;form1***.

So, to recap, to fetch the reference to form DOM element, you would have to use DOM ID of the form, which you could easily do with **[$Component](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_variables_global_component.htm)** field. Like so:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('{!$Component.form1}').reset();
}
```

Comment: it showing the alert but it is not sweeping the value in text box

Comment: i have two button are there first button is to reset and second button is to show list .when i click on the reset button before click the list it is reset the form when i click the reset button after clicking the list it is not working.i need that mainly it has to reset after clicking the list button

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you don't call your form properly from your javascript method try something like :

```
<apex:form>
<apex:inputtext value="{!text1}"/>
<apex:inputtext value="{!text2}"/>
<apex:commandButton value="Reset" onclick="this.form.reset();return false;"/>
<apex:commandButton value="List" action="{!list}"/>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: No Not working.

Comment: @Teja can you be more constructive?

Comment: i have two button are there first button is to reset and second button is to show list .when i click on the reset button before click the list it is reset the form when i click the reset button after clicking the list it is not working.i need that mainly it has to reset after clicking the list button

Answer (score 0):

Since you already are using **jquery**:

Change this two lines:

```
<apex:form id="form1">

document.getElementById(form1).reset();
```

for this:

```
<apex:form id="js-form1">

$('form[id$="js-form1"]')[0].reset();
```

Comment: No Not Working .

Comment: I updated my sample

Comment: @Teja can you be more constructive?

Comment: if you try where I've posted it should works

Comment: i have two button are there first button is to reset and second button is to show list .when i click on the reset button before click the list it is reset the form when i click the reset button after clicking the list it is not working.i need that mainly it has to reset after clicking the list button

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your function.

It uses jQuery. First step is to alias jQuery because using $ conflicts with other Salesforce libraries. Then we are going to use a selector to find the element that ends with form1. This returns an array, so we need just the first one in the array.

```
var j$ = jQuery.noConflict(); 
function myFunction() {
    j$("[id$='form1']")[0].reset();
}
```

Comment: i have two button are there first button is to reset and second button is to show list .when i click on the reset button before click the list it is reset the form when i click the reset button after clicking the list it is not working.i need that mainly it has to reset after clicking the list button

Comment: Then you can't do that with JavaScript. Your reset button will need to call an Apex method that nulls out all the values. The problem is that the list button is updating the page, so the Reset doesn't know what it was originally.